# How to refactor database schema with dual-purpose foreign key

Tags: sql, database

I have two general types of "users", `Person` and `Page`. They can preform the same actions (voting, commenting, posting, etc.), but they have intrinsically different information. In a nutshell, a `Person` has a `first_name`, `last_name`, `gender`, and `birthday`. A `Page` has a `title`, `description`, and `basic_info`.

Both Person and Page can perform the *same* actions throughout the system, so when designing the database schema, I feel that it is necessary relate everything back to a central `id` column. Otherwise, I think the complexity of the system would increase drastically (although maybe I am incorrect in saying this.)

Given this, I would like to have a "mapping" table. For example, let's call this table `Map`. `Map` has an `id` (the central id which everything is identified by), `destination_id` (the id of either the person or the page, depending on the next column...) and `type` (either Person or Page).

If, for example, `type` is "Person", I know to look in the User table, and if `type` is "Page", I know to look in the Page table to get the necessary info.

I am not happy with this design because it introduces a "dual-purpose foreign key." -- I have a "Foreign Key" in the `Map` table which can refer to any number of other tables.

How do I refactor this so that I can:

1. Preferably, allow for additional user_types to be added (Person, Page, and then Group, for instance)
2. Get rid of that dual-purpose foreign key

A possible alternative: Have two columns in the `Map` table, `page_id` and `person_id`, both of which are actual Foreign Keys, but only one of which is not null. Whichever one is not null is obviously a true Foreign Key to the proper user_type's info (Page or Person).

This seems moderately reasonable, but it doesn't necessarily satisfy my 1st condition as 'cleanly' as I would like, and it seems rather clunky.

How can I refactor this?

Comment: A page can be treated as if it were a user. I will edit to make more  clear hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the map table, move the Type column to the User table, and have foreign key columns on both the Person and Page tables that reference the primary key on the User table.